# How can I compile Gnu C in windows

Tags: c++, c, mingw, codeblocks, gnu

Too those who know how, this may be a stupid question, but I'll be asking it anyway because I need some pointers.

The library I'm trying to compile is the SPro toolkit for speech signal processing which is written in (for lack of a better description) Gnu C++

It's a library written for unix and I want to compile it in windows. As much as an object exercise in porting code from, as anything.

Toward that end I have installed code::blocks and a MinGW compiler. I read that I could also use cgywn and that this would be introducing a layer interpreting the gnu c before executing it natively, but let me leave that to the side for the moment.

The first issue I ran into was that the #includes need a little love - ok no problem with that.

But now I find that

```
scopy.c|462|error: 'SIZEOF_SHORT' undeclared (first use in this function)|
```

I also installed visual Studio C++ and get the same.

I gather that SIZEOF_CHAR, SIZEOF_SHORT, SIZEOF_LONG, SIZEOF_FLOAT and SIZEOF_DOUBLE would be declared, in a header or somewhere.

Unfortunalty I don't have any idea where, so have no idea what to include to have access to the definitions.

What should I include?

Do I need to define these constants myself as I am in a different environment?

Also I may be barking up the wrong tree, any help is appreciated.

Comment: run `cygwin` and then compile gnu c++ .  It may help

Comment: Why would SIZEOF_SHORT, etc., be declared anywhere? They're not part of any standard I'm aware of.

Comment: They would be declared in the spro code if they were not system defined. There are no dependencies. But they are not in the spro code.  i was thinking a lowlevel c compiler may define them as a way to allow them to be redefined for portability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#define SIZEOF_SHORT sizeof(short)
#define SIZEOF_CHAR sizeof(char)
```

Repeat for all other types.